# How to use multiple conditions which are variables in SQL in VBA code?

Tags: sql, vba

I am trying to run a select query statement like this in a table from VBA:

```
variable_a = 1
variable_b = 2
```

after proper database connection the query goes like:

```
SQry = "select CONCAT(Col1,Colb) as TOTAL from MyTable where Col1 = '" & variable_a & "' AND '" & variable_b & "'"
```

But it fails.\

How can I use that "AND" in between 2 or more statements which are variables of VBA? It works fine with one condition but the "AND" or "OR" part messes it up.

Thank you

Tried dividing the query into several lines like:

```
sq1 = "select CONCAT(Col1,Colb) AS TOTAL from MyTable" & 
sq2 = "where Col1 = " & _
sq3 = " '" & variable_a & "'" & _
sq4 = " ' and ' " & _
sq5 = " Col2 = '" & variable_b & "'"
```

Comment: So what is `Debug.Print SQry` output? The line should be at least `SQry = "select CONCAT(Col1,Colb) as TOTAL from MyTable where Col1 = '" & variable_a & "' AND Col1 = '" & variable_b & "'"`. If fields are numeric type then remove `'` around concatenated variables.

Comment: *Tried dividing the query into several lines like:* ... and what happened? Errors? Undesired results? By the way, advise on your database and really look into SQL parameterization for readability and maintainability.

Comment: fix sql4, remove single quote,  to be   sq4 = "  and  " & _

Comment: You're missing the space between `MyTable` and `where`.

Comment: In first query, `where Col1 = '" & variable_a & "' AND '" & variable_b & "'` should probably be `where Col1 = '" & variable_a & "' AND Col2 = '" & variable_b & "'`

Comment: Your query resolves to:
select CONCAT(Col1,Colb) as TOTAL
from MyTable 
where Col1 = '1' AND '2'
which makes no sense. Are you sure you don't mean something like
select CONCAT(Col1,Colb) as TOTAL
from MyTable 
where Col1 = '1' OR Col1 = '2'

Comment: @Weston E, no, the query is for avoiding duplicates to be inserted into the table.

Comment: Thank you @GMB, I missed that.